# How to update google apps in miui5

Tags: google-play-store, google-apps, miui

I have purchased a Redmi 1s mobile. It has miui v5. It seems that we can't update Google apps in miui.
So, how can we update Google apps in miui. 
I've just seen that the updates are shown in apps like 9apps and mobogenie.
Is it safe to download the updates from these apps? Or 
How can I make Google play to show these updates?

Comment: Do you mean the gapps package, or individual apps on the Play Store?

Comment: The google apps package

Comment: And are you asking about *updating* (i.e. the apps are already installed), or *installing* them in the first place? Because if they are already installed, they take care for their updates themselves (or rather *Google Play* does).

Comment: In miui google apps do not update themselves. I'm asking about updating apps.

Comment: Also updates for google apps are not shown in playstore in miui.

Comment: Have you tried using google installer ? http://en.miui.com/thread-17910-1-1.html

Comment: Google installer only shows the option to install but not update

Comment: But i was able to update the google apps from playstore..

Comment: But playstore doesn't show updates for Google apps in my mobile.

Comment: Try this..uninstall any of the Google apps and install the older version of that app and check update from playstore.

Comment: Try to extract the apk from other phones using apk extracter and install it thereafter in your phone.

Answer (score 3):

try with that

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2397942

it replaces your play store and google apps with the last official versions

you have to flash it from  Recovery

Comment: This should help but he needs to be rooted for that. Im not whether his phone is rooted or not.

Comment: You need a custom recovery